# How to safely install fuse on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: fuse

I need to install fuse on Ubuntu 22.04.  I've tried installing via `snap install fuse` but that didn't work, so what is the safest way to install fuse on Ubuntu 22.04?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`fuse` is present in the Ubuntu repositories, and therefore can be safely installed.

However, it conflicts with a newer version of fuse, `fuse3`, which is installed by default. If you choose to use `fuse` rather than `fuse3`, you will lose some functionality that depends on `fuse3`.

Installing `fuse` indeed will cause the removal of

```
fuse3 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gvfs-fuse ntfs-3g
  xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

In addition, the metapackages `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` will be removed.

`fuse` is in the software repository. Installation therefore is *safe*:

```
sudo apt install fuse
```

but you have to accept the consequences on functionality of the default desktop.

Comment: doing so will even remove xwayland and more; ubuntu sucks

Comment: This answer is useful even to repair the system in case you install "fuse" on Ubuntu>22.04. Removing the package "fuse" and reinstalling the packages "fuse3 gnome-shell... and so on" will fix the problem. Thanks @vanadium!

Comment: This ought to ask for a switch such as `--just_do_it` and not allow inadvertent removal of packages required for proper desktop operation!  I inadvertently installed fuse then `gnome-settings` disappeared and I wondered why until I checked `/var/log/apt/history.log` and saw the error of my ways...

Comment: @AnthonyK Then you will end up with a borked system. That is why we have a package manager: to ensure that installed packages are compatible with each other.

Comment: That's true @vanadium - this was exactly my point.  I've seen before where the system asks you provide a switch - such as what `rm -rf /` asks you to do to avoid damaging your system - so that a user doesn't inadvertently uninstall packages as important as `ubuntu-desktop` on a desktop.

Comment: @vanadium too right you are. Installing `fuse` on gnome will bork `gdm` and prevent login (removes the `Gnome` option for login). Dropping to the command line you can `sudo apt reinstall ubunutu-gnome-desktop` then login again BUT make sure you select the `Gnome` window manager from the GDM settings. Also "GDM" lol - obvious anagram.

Answer (score 15):

See this: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE

> For example, on Ubuntu (>= 22.04):
>
> Warning: Do not install the fuse package as of 22.04 or > you may break your system
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository universe
> sudo apt install libfuse2
> ```

Comment: It seems that this may not work very well. I could not run one AppImage app. I got these: "error: ac63-[2022-06-06 13:59:07] GPU process crashed"

Comment: For me it did work.  
Tried with BalenaEtcher and worked fine.
We never know :)

Comment: Yes, `libfuse2` NOT `fuse` for >= 22.04
If you already installed `fuse` remove it. Then reinstall `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. Don't forget to reselect the `Gnome` window manager at login (which disappeared when you installed `fuse` causing logins to FAIL.)