# Jetbrains Toolbox and fuse2

Tags: apt, fuse

I have set up Ubuntu 22.10 and trying to install jetbrains-toolbox on it.

After kicked toolbox included in the archive file, it says it requires fuse, so I have installed it with `apt install fuse` and logged out. Then GUI started to crash and never comes up.

I have recovered it with Alt-F2 -> login in CUI -> `apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and successfully regains GUI login panel, but, according to the messages generated by apt, it seems that fuse2 have been removed and ubuntu-desktop installs fuse3 as well alongside.

I suspects now that jetbrains-toolbox is not compatible with fuse3, and ubuntu-desktop is not compatible with fuse2. How I can solve this and run toolbox on Ubuntu 22.10? Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `fuse` will indeed cause problems as it triggers the uninstallation of `fuse3`, which is used by some core components (as you observed and as is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409500/1668986)).

You can however install `libfuse2` which will allow jetbrains-toolbox to start.

Comment: Thanks! It (install only `libfuse2`) solved a problem.

Comment: Thanks! That one really helped!